# How to add a view behind other view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, view, core-animation

I want to add a view under my tab bar analog in iOS and then show it with animation coming from behind it. But when I use my code, the view that must come from behind my tab bar  overlaps my tab bar for a while.

[image: tab bar and a view that shows when tab bar button pressed]

This is my code:

```
- (void)handlePressedButton {
if (pressedButton.selected) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-196.0, 0.0);
    CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
    [leftPanelView setTransform:transform1];
    [movedView setTransform:transform2];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    pressedButton.selected = NO;
}
else {
    pressedButton.selected = YES;
    if (leftPanelView) {
        [leftPanelView removeFromSuperview];
        leftPanelView = nil;
    }
    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(-196, 0, 236, 748);
    leftPanelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    leftPanelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left-nav-content.png"]];

    // Code to populate leftPanelView according to what button is pressed.
    [self populateLeftPanelView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:leftPanelView];
    CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(236.0, 0.0);
    CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(112.0, 0.0);
    [leftPanelView setTransform:transform1];
    [movedView setTransform:transform2];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}

Here the leftPanelView is the view that must come under a tab bar. Moved view is another view, that is at the right of left panel (don't mind it)

Comment: Check if this works :   [self.navigationController.view insertSubview: <subview> belowSubview:self.navigationController.navigationBar];

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Besides `addSubview`, there are other methods you can rely on to add your view:

```
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– insertSubview:atIndex:
```

You can control the index (actually z-index, or layer order) of the view using these methods.

Comment: This should be the right answer. the above answer doesn't answer what was asked.

Answer (score 57):

try [sendSubviewToBack](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sendSubviewToBack%3a)

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:leftPanelView];
```

Comment: I accept your answer, coz you've sent it after 2 mins, I posted. I think it's fair.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.  All this does is move a view to the back of the subview chain.  The answer below from He Shiming is correct.

Answer (score 22):

## Swift 5

**Insert** a view **below** another view in the view hierarchy:

```
view.insertSubview(subview1, belowSubview: subview2)
```

**Insert** a view **above** another view in the view hierarchy:

```
view.insertSubview(subview1, aboveSubview: subview2)
```

**Insert** a subview **at the specified index**:

```
view.insertSubview(subview, at: index)
```

---

**Move** the specified subview so that it appears **behind** its siblings:

```
subview1.sendSubviewToBack(subview2)
```

**Move** the specified subview so that it appears **on top** of its siblings:

```
subview1.bringSubviewToFront(subview2)
```

---

**Exchange** the subviews **at the specified indices**:

```
view.exchangeSubview(at: index1, withSubviewAt: index2)
```

Answer (score 7):

Oh, I found a solution myself. I added after this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:leftPanelView];
```

this line:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:leftPanelView];
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 5**

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(leftPanelView)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another nice idea is to give the Subviews a **tag**.

**Swift**

```
mainView.addSubView(topView)
mainView.addSubView(bottomView)

topView.tag = 2

mainView.insertSubview(bottomView, belowSubview: mainView.viewWithTag(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Objective-C

**Insert** a view **below** another view in the view hierarchy:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)subview1 
         belowSubview:(UIView *)subview2;
```

**Insert** a view **above** another view in the view hierarchy:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)subview1 
         aboveSubview:(UIView *)subview2;
```

**Insert** a subview **at the specified index**:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view 
              atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

---

**Move** the specified subview so that it appears **behind** its siblings:

```
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

**Move** the specified subview so that it appears **on top** of its siblings:

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
```

---

**Exchange** the subviews **at the specified indices**:

```
- (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 
            withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2;
```